# Plotting a graph using Haskell

Tags: haskell, graph, plot

Is that possible to plot a simple graph using Haskell ?
Can any of you show me how to do that ?

The graph should contain at lest 3 points

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[haskell-chart](https://github.com/timbod7/haskell-chart) seems to be good.

The [wiki](https://github.com/timbod7/haskell-chart/wiki) contains a list of graphs drawn using that package.

Answer (score 7):

Apart from Chart, there are some very good language-agnostic plotting libraries/systems, usable from Haskell. I use Vega and matplotlib myself.

## Vega

You can use [Vega-Lite](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/tutorials/getting_started.html) with the Haskell package [hvega](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hvega), which gives you an html file with a chart drawn with the vega-lite js library.

Basic usage:

```
import           Graphics.Vega.VegaLite
main = do
 toHtmlFile "myplot.html" $ toVegaLite
  [ dataFromUrl "rows.tsv" [TSV]
  , mark Bar [MTooltip TTEncoding]
  , enc []
  , height 600
  , width 400
  ]
 where enc = encoding
      . position X [ PName "date"
                   , PmType Ordinal
                   ]
      . position Y [ PName "joy"
                   , PmType Quantitative
                   ]
      . color [MName "activity", MmType Nominal]
```

(Then put the tsv and html files in a directory served by a web server, e.g. `$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in that directory.) This example gives a stacked bar chart of three columns (assuming `rows.tsv` has the column names used in the code):

[image: vega-haskell plot example]

The documentation has lots of examples: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hvega/docs/Graphics-Vega-Tutorials-VegaLite.html

## matplotlib

If you can live with installing some Python deps, [matplotlib](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/matplotlib#readme) makes it easy to interactively plot and explore.

Simple example:

```
onscreen $ let b = bar [21..23] in
   b [56,57,56] @@ [o2 "color" "#4C78A8"] 
 % b [26,24,25] @@ [o2 "color" "#F58518"] 
 % b [16,15,14] @@ [o2 "color" "#E45756"]
```

[image: matplotlib-haskell plot example]

See the [readme](https://github.com/abarbu/matplotlib-haskell/) for more examples.

## Plotly

[Plotly](https://plotly.com/r/) (originally for R) is usable from Haskell with the package [plotlyhs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/plotlyhs). You get out a standalone html page with an interactive plot.

Example usage: https://glutamate.github.io/plotlyhs/

## Gnuplot

There are various packages that create gnuplot scripts which can be used to make png's etc: https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=gnuplot