# Plot in Haskell

Tags: haskell, graph, haskell-stack

How can I plot graphs or others discrete structures like trees in Haskell? I would like to use colors and put some text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/

Comment: please note that asking for libraries is considered off-topic here

Comment: Ok. Let me write the question in other way

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824756/plotting-a-graph-using-haskell?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting a graph using Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824756/plotting-a-graph-using-haskell)